# How to stop a specific key from working in Python

Tags: python, keyboard

My laptop keyboard has a bug and it sometimes presses the number 5 randomly so i tried many things and they didn't work, I tried programming a code that can stop it but i couldn't because i am a beginner.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
disable = keyboard.pressed('5')
if deni:
  KeyboardInterrupt
  continue
```

hopefully this doesn't need imports

Comment: What OS system are you running?

Comment: iam using windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not belong here. You should have put it in https://superuser.com/ as it would have been a whole lot easier and more effective to do it in some other programming language. But if you want to do it in python, first learn python.

#### Other Options

1. Try pressing "Fn and Num Lock" or if you don't have "Num Lock" do "Fn and Caps Lock.
2. Try reinstalling your keyboard driver.
3. If your keyboard has gotten water inside of it, then put it in rice and let it sit for 2 to 3 days
4. Buy a new keyboard

#### Resources

- http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1972361/keyboard-keys-typing-wrong-multiple-letters.html