# How do I cancel keyboard input event from Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a keyboard that doesn't have a ten-key.
So I created a program that allows you to use the ten-key on a keyboard that doesn't have a ten-key.

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pag

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('right ctrl'):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('i'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('1')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('2')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('3')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('4')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('l'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('5')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed(';'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('6')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed(','):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('7')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('.'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('8')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('/'):
            pag.press('backspace')
            pag.press('9')
        else:
            pass
```

**Let's get to the point**

I used
`pag.press('backspace')`

But I want to cancel the keyboard input event.

except for backspace.

What should I do?

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem is. Did you want the code to press both backspace and a number to simulate the numpad? If so, you can use pyautogui's hotkey function like so: pyautogui.hotkey('backscape', 9)

Comment: very interesting - i know python can be used as a keylogger and can press keys, but i can't seem to find anything on breaking keys except this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235211/how-to-stop-a-specific-key-from-working-in-python/48236123 which was a bit rudely shut down

Comment: I want to use

right ctrl + 
IOP
KL;
,./

to

123
456
789

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, below is the solution using **python keyboard** library:

```
keyboard.remap_key('i', '1')
keyboard.remap_key('o', '2')
```

and so on...